# Getting "Unexpected Error" while trying to Sign up in WSO2 API Manager Devportal

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to signup in WSO2 API Manager but it is giving me "Unexpected Error" and in logs i was able to figure out the below logs,

"IdentityManagementEndpointUtil Exception while retrieving error details from original exception. Original exception:
org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.endpoint.util.client.SelfRegistrationMgtClientException: Error while check username validity for user : tester1"

I checked whether self sign up configuration was disabled but it was already in enabled state so that is not an issue.

Comment: Can you provide the APIM version and what are the configuration changes you applied for the setup ?

Comment: Hi We are using version 4.1.0 of APIM and PFA deployment.tom file for your reference.

Comment: PFB Config URL in the below url,
https://github.com/buvnesh/Learning/blob/feature-buvi-learning/deployment%20(1).toml